# Thumbnail on modal with button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have trouble getting the value of the second item when i click the second button(labeled image2). How am I able to get that? Only the first button is able to get the value. Here's my code. Please help me, thank you.

```
<div id="div1" align="center" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; border: solid 1px;" align="center">
        <img src="img/default.jpg" alt="no image" style="width: 95%; height: 95%; margin-top: 5px ;">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 150px; border: solid 1px;" align="center">
        <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle" style="font-size: 15px;"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-md btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-md btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imgmodal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="imgmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                <h3>TECHNICIANS</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php include("getTech.php") ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnSelectImg").click(function(){
            alert(document.getElementById('btnSelectImg').textContent);
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the [modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCNou.png)

this is my code to get the items from database. `getTech.pph`

```
<?php 

$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_image";

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("FAILED TO CONNECT : " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if($result->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $imgname = $row['_imageName'];
        $imgpath = $row['_imagepath'];

        // echo "<script> alert(); </script>";

        echo "<div id='divImg' style='margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 20px; display: inline-block;' align='center'>";
        echo "<img src='". $imgpath. "' alt='no image' class='img-thumbnail'><br>";
        echo "<button class='btn btn-deafult' id='btnSelectImg' style='margin-top: 5px;'>".$imgname."</button>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='path' value='". $imgpath."'>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

} 

?>
```

this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD5tH.png) when i click the image1 button. but when i click the image2, nothing happen. meaning nothing is obtain. I think that is because of it has the same id. I am not sure. please help me on this. I hope this is clear enough. thanks a lot. I'll appreciate your help! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using id `btnSelectImg` for two button. id should be unique.

in getTech.php change

```
echo "<button class='btn btn-deafult' id='btnSelectImg' style='margin-top: 5px;'>".$imgname."</button>";
```

to

```
echo "<button class='btn btn-deafult btnSelectImg'  style='margin-top: 5px;'>".$imgname."</button>";
```

then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btnSelectImg").click(function(){
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    });
</script>
```